# Array in another bigger array including duplicates using Linq

Tags: c#

Example: `Array1.Intersect(Array2)` checks for only distinct elements.

Is there an elegant way using linq to get the result which contains even duplicates? The result should be case-insensitive. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make an example with desired input and output?

Comment: input: string[] Arr1= new string[] { "a","a", "b", "y" };
string[] Arr2= new string[] {"s", "a", "z", "b", "c", "a"}; Output  {"a", "a", "b"} but not {"a", "b"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as efficient but clear:

```
var inboth = Array1.Where(Array2.Contains);
```

**Edit** according to your case-insensitive comment:

```
inboth = Array1.Where(s => Array2.Contains(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: converting `Array2` to a `HashSet` might make things more efficient if there are enough elements in `Array1`, either way this works.

Comment: Thanks Tim. However I forgot to mention that the result should also contain case-insensitive elements.

Comment: @user1191177: You haven't even told that the arrays are `String[]`. However, give me a moment.

Comment: you could consider using the current culture over ordinal, I know ordinal would be faster but in some cultres things change more when you shift case (I think.) The HashSet option is still available, as shown in my improved answer.

Comment: Most people want to compare culture-agnostic and even if he wants to take the current culture into account, as far as i know `Ordinal` passes [the turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) since it behaves like `ToUpper`(instead of the dangerous `ToLower`).

Answer (score 0):

after your comment,

```
var secondSet = new HashSet<string>(
    array2,
    StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

var intersectSequence = array2.Where(secondSet.Contains);
```